# Update another field using ajax

Tags: java, events, primefaces

View:

```
<h:form id="ExamrequisitionsCreateForm">

     <p:selectOneMenu id="examId" value="#{examrequisitionsController.selected.examId}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.EditExamrequisitionsRequiredMessage_examId}">
          <f:selectItems value="#{examsController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                    var="examIdItem"
                    itemValue="#{examIdItem}"/>
          <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{examrequisitionsController.getPriceExam(examItem.id)}" render="ExamrequisitionsCreateForm:price" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

          <p:inputText id="price" value="#{examrequisitionsController.selected.price}" title="#{bundle.CreateExamrequisitionsTitle_price}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.CreateExamrequisitionsRequiredMessage_price}">

</h:form>
```

Controller:

```
public BigDecimal getPriceExam(int id) {
    EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SystemCardiologyReportsPU").createEntityManager();
     List<Exams> examsList = em.createNamedQuery("Exams.findById").
                 setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
     return examsList == null ? null : examsList.get(0).getPrice();
}
```

I'm trying to update the field `price` after the event `change` is actioned in exam.
How can I make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following :

1. Remove

   ```
      <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{examrequisitionsController.getPriceExam(examItem.id)}" render="ExamrequisitionsCreateForm:price" />
   ```

And add

```
  <p:ajax  listener="#{examrequisitionsController.updatePrice}" update="price"/>
```

2. In your controller :

   ```
      public void updatePrice (){
           EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SystemCardiologyReportsPU").createEntityManager();
      List<Exams> examsList = em.createNamedQuery("Exams.findById").
            setParameter("id", this.selected.examId ).getResultList();
      this.selected.price == null ? null : examsList.get(0).getPrice();
   }
   ```

   Your listener just need to update the Value that is bound to the input text and your ajax call just needs to update that.

Comment: If you could up vote answers on your questions it would be awesome. Thanks